# Do I need a vapor-barrier for laminate if my current floor is raised off a concrete floor?

Tags: vapor-barrier, laminate-floor

My basement was finished in the 50s or 60s, including a real white-pine hardwood floor. It's raised off the concrete floor by nominal 2x4s as furring strips. The floor has seen better days, and for various other reasons, I wish to use laminate flooring instead of trying to repair.

Most manufacturers recommend a vapor-barrier for applications to concrete, but since this is not directly onto the concrete, do I still need the vapor / moisture barrier?

The laminate I will be applying already has underlayment, which I understand is not at all the same.

Comment: This is an spur-of-the-moment comment, so treat it accordingly. I wouldn't give this any more thought. I'd just go get some roofing felt and put it down and be done with it. It's not that expensive, and you'd have the peace of mind of knowing you will not have a moisture problem from below.

Comment: Personally, I would install one. Any moisture and mold build up can resonate through your furring strips up to your flooring. It's never good when wood comes into direct contact with concrete, unless it's pressure treated and has room to breathe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contractor never added a vapor barrier. The basement is incredibly dry, never any trace of mold in places where the floor had come up, so this was not a concern. Too late either way, so answering the question to close out this question.